# NoPermissions (FileSystemError) When Attempting Git Commit in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am new to Git and attempting to use VSCode as the configured core.editor. I'm able to successfully complete commits when using the `git commit -m "commit message"` method within Terminal, but when I omit -m and just use `git commit` in order to enter a commit message within VSCode I receive the following error message in VSCode:

**The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to read file '/filepath/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG' (NoPermissions (FileSystemErrror): An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.)**

Im using Git version 2.38.0 and VSCode version 1.77.2

I have:

- Verified that VS Code is my default editor using `git config core.editor` (returns expected code --wait).
- In VSCode used Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH.
- Uninstalled then reinstalled 'code' command in PATH.
- Uninstalled VSCode completely and reinstalled it.
- Moved VSCode from Downloads file to Applications file.
- Deleted the COMMIT_EDITMSG file (it just returns and I receive the same error message the next time I try).
- Checked permissions for entire directory and confirmed that I have read/write permissions.
- Changed the default code editor to TextEdit - when I did this, I was able to successfully use the `git commit` command and enter my own commit message in TextEdit.

I am also able to open my .gitconfig file in VSCode without issue using `git config --global -e`.

I am losing my mind! Any ideas on other fixes to try? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: do you get this error if you try with different editors in `core.editor`? If not, it might be a VS Code bug.

Comment: @user I tried it with TextEditor and it works fine there. I agree, I think this is a VS Code bug, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it given that thesis.

Comment: If you want _extra_ eyes on what you think may be a VS Code bug, you can [open an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) (make sure to [edit] your post here to link to it so readers here can also subscribe to it!)